# Java throwing division by zero error?

Tags: java, math

In an attempt to relearn how to write code in Java I've been going through some problems from Project Euler. The following code I've written is to solve problem 3: finding the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143.

```
public class ProjectEuler {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ProjectEuler t = new ProjectEuler();
    System.out.println(t.findLargestPrime(600851475143L));

}

public Boolean isPrime(int x) {
    Boolean answer = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < x/2; i++) {
        if (x%i == 0) {
            answer = false;
    }

}
    return answer;
}

public int findLargestPrime(Long max) {
    int largest = 1;
    for (int i = 2 ; i < max/2; i++) {
        if (max%i == 0 && isPrime(i) && i > largest) {
            largest = i;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}

}
```

However, when I run it the code throws an arithmetic error because I'm trying to divide by zero? The actual error message is shown here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at projecteuler.ProjectEuler.findLargestPrime(ProjectEuler.java:37)
at projecteuler.ProjectEuler.main(ProjectEuler.java:19)
```

I don't know if I've made a stupid mistake somewhere or if it's a quirk of Java that I don't understand? Could anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [help/on-topic] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Division `/ 0` or modulo `% 0` have this effect. I did not see anything dubious. By the way, better use boolean and long (the data types) instead of Boolean and Long (the wrapper classes). Go to line 37 of ProjectEuler.java. After `answer = false; break;`

Comment: Your code is going out of bounds because you are using int as the param type...use long in method params

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but I'd suggest you do `max = max / i` each time you find a prime factor. Looping to 600 billion could take a long time... Also, this way you do not even have to check whether `i` is prime.

Comment: Once you fix your type error, you can make your program faster. First off, what use is `largest`?  `i` is always going up, never down, so it will *always* be larger than `largest`.  Second, you can search for a prime factor *smaller than the square root* of the number, and then divide the number by the factor. Now you have a smaller number that has the same largest prime factor as your original number, and you know a bound on the size of its smallest prime factor.

Comment: Also, your program contains an error; what if you put in, say 7 as the number. It returns 1 as the largest prime factor of 7, but 1 is not a prime number and not the largest prime factor of 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for (int i = 2 ; i < max/2; i++)` will eventually overflow (because `600851475143 / 2` is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) and eventually `i` will equal to `0` when it will happen `max%i` will throw that exception.

Change `i` to `long` if you want to prevent it from happeninng (you should also change all the other `int`'s to `long`).

Comment: That's totally fixed it! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the actual question, but: You do not have to check all the numbers up to `max`, and you do not even have to do any checks whether a divisor is prime. You just have to (repeatedly) divide the `max` by any divisor `i` you found.

```
long l = 600851475143L;
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(l); i++) {
    if (l % i == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
        l /= i;
        i--;
    }
}
System.out.println("--> " + l);
```

This way, you *know* that this divisor must be prime -- if it were composite, `max` would already have been divided by its components. This also means that you do not have to loop all the way up to `max` (which, for the given value, would take a really long time), but only up to the largest prime divisor, which might be much much smaller. And once you reach `sqrt(l)` -- for the *current* value of `l`, not the original! -- you can stop, since there can not be any divisors higher than that, and the remaining value of `l` will be the final (and thus, largest) prime factor.

Thus, this reduces the complexity from about O(n²) to about O(n<sup>½</sup>).

Comment: This is a much more intelligent solution, thank you.

Comment: I would really like to know why both these answers just got downvoted...

Comment: There is also another downvote to my question at the same time so it's probably something against me, maybe he also downvoted your answer to cover his tracks?